# Stored procedure returning a number when it find something

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to create a stored procedure to find a customer in a table, returning 1 if it found something and 0 if it does not. I have the idea of using exception to handle the 0 part, but I do not know how to return the number that I wanted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIND_CUSTOMER 
(
  CUSTOMER_ID IN NUMBER 
, FOUND OUT NUMBER 
) AS 
BEGIN
SELECT CUST_NO
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE CUST_NO = customer_id;

EXCEPTION 
WHEN no_data_found 
THEN found := 0; 
END FIND_CUSTOMER;
```

Where do I put the return statement for it to work properly ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To return a value, you need to create a function not a procedure. Then, you would return the variable you populated with a `select into`. If you really want a procedure then populate `found` and don't use any `return` clause.

Comment: I think OP asks for `return statement` but not for `return clause` @WilliamRobertson

Comment: Whether you prefer to call it a clause or a statement, in a procedure all you have is `return;` which doesn't seem to be what they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just missed **INTO** clause for the *SELECT* statement. You can recreate procedure like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_customer(
                                          customer_id customer.cust_no%TYPE,
                                          found       OUT INT
                                         ) AS                                         
BEGIN
  SELECT SIGN(cust_no)
    INTO found
    FROM customer
   WHERE cust_no = customer_id;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    found := 0;
END;
/
```

or prefer creating like the one below through use of a simple implicit cursor where no need for an **INTO** clause and exception handling even, and just an initialization value(*zero*) used for the out parameter such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_customer(
                                          customer_id customer.cust_no%TYPE,
                                          found       OUT INT
                                         ) AS
BEGIN
  found := 0;
  FOR c IN
    (
      SELECT SIGN(cust_no) AS fnd
        FROM customer
       WHERE cust_no = customer_id
    )
  LOOP
    found := c.fnd;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I've used `SIGN()` function in order to return the value (**1**) presuming all values of `cust_no` are positive integers logically.